# Xamarin Forms BaseViewModel with Navigation

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, mvvm, viewmodel

Hola amigos quiero crear un BaseViewModel con **INavigation** y **INotifyPropertyChanged**, hasta ahi creo que todo bien pero cuando quiero heredar mi clase base a otro ViewModel obtengo un error de este tipo :

> CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'navigation' of 'BaseViewModel.BaseViewModel(INavigation)'

Alguien podria decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

Esta es mi clase base:

```
namespace Mvvm_Practice.ViewModels
{
    public partial class BaseViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
    #region props
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get => _title;
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region interfaces
    //private INavigation _navigation;
    public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public BaseViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = navigation;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    }
   }
```

Y aqui mi clase que hereda

```
namespace Mvvm_Practice.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel  
    {
    private string _valor;        
    public string Valor
    {
        get => _valor;
        set
        {
            _valor = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Valor));
        }
    }
     
    public ICommand NavPage2Command;
    public MainViewModel()// justo aqui me tira ese error
    {
         
        NavPage2Command = new Command(async () => await GoToPage2());
    }

    private async Task GoToPage2()
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: te estaria faltando pasarle a tu constructor de tu clase viewmodelbase la propiedad INavigation

Answer (score 1):

Tenes un constructor creado en tu clase base y en tu clase que heredas te esta faltando llamarlo y pasarle a tu constructor base el parametro.

```
namespace Mvvm_Practice.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel  
    {
    private string _valor;        
    public string Valor
    {
        get => _valor;
        set
        {
            _valor = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Valor));
        }
    }
     
    public ICommand NavPage2Command;
    public MainViewModel(INavigation navigation) : base(navigation )
    {
         
        NavPage2Command = new Command(async () => await GoToPage2());
    }

    private async Task GoToPage2()
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
    }
    }
  }
```